# generate JavaScript code in an Angularjs component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to generate JavaScript code

```
<script>
...
</script>
```

in a component variable and use this variable let's say `scriptJs` in the template of the component

```
{{ scriptJs }}
```

Is that possible? If not, how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{scriptJs }}    
</body>

<script>
var c=angular.module('myApp',[])
c.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.scriptJs ="imtah"
});
</script>
```